# Menu is order dependant

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I'm trying to implement a menu that can choose different themes and it works to some extent but I can only change theme if the theme I choose is below the current theme in the list.

I've been following this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But it doesn't work.. I've been trying to check the "sender" object as well but what is it that you actually compare the sender to? Is it the name of the MenuItem or what? I tried that but no luck there either.

This is the code for the clickEvent:

```
        if (swTheme.IsChecked)
        {
            SetTheme(MainWindow.Themes.StarWars);
            redTheme.IsChecked = false;
            greenTheme.IsChecked = false;
            defaultTheme.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else if (redTheme.IsChecked)
        {
            SetTheme(MainWindow.Themes.Red);
            greenTheme.IsChecked = false;
            swTheme.IsChecked = false;
            defaultTheme.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else if (greenTheme.IsChecked)
        {
            SetTheme(MainWindow.Themes.Green);
            redTheme.IsChecked = false;
            swTheme.IsChecked = false;
            defaultTheme.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            defaultTheme.IsChecked = true;
            SetTheme(MainWindow.Themes.Default);
            redTheme.IsChecked = false;
            greenTheme.IsChecked = false;
            swTheme.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

Here is the XAML-code for the menu:

```
<MenuItem Header="Themes" Click="themeChoice">
                <MenuItem Name="defaultTheme" Header="Default" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
                <MenuItem Name="greenTheme"  Header="Green" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False"/>
                <MenuItem Name="redTheme" Header="Red" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False"/>
                <MenuItem Name="swTheme" Header="Star Wars" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False"/>
            </MenuItem>
```

And like I said I can only change theme if the theme I click is below the currently enabled theme. So right now I can just go Default -> green -> red -> sw and I can't spot my error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handler is called before the state of the `MenuItem`s are changed, and your if statement gives precedence to items that are visually higher in the menu.

Instead of listening to the `Menu` event, listen to the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events of the individual `MenuItem` instances that you have. Of course, you can write a generic `OnChecked` and `OnUnchecked` event handler and assign all 4 `MenuItem`s to the same handler.

The `Checked` and `Unchecked` events are raised after the `MenuItem` state has been changed, so your logic should go through correctly.

```
void MenuItemChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var menuItem = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;

   // Uncheck all other items
   ...

   // Change theme to what the current menu item specifies
   ...

   // Mark the event handled
   e.Handled = true;
}
```